# Kohana -- Command Line

Tags: php, kohana

I'm trying to "faux-fork" a process (an email being sent via SMTP) in my web application, and the application is built on Kohana.

```
    $command = 'test/email';
    exec('php index.php '.$command.' > /dev/null/ &', $errors, $response);
```

I'm getting an error --

`Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME`

When I look into Kohana's index.php file, I see that it is looking for a variable named SERVER_NAME, but I guess it is coming up NULL because Kohana couldn't detect this value and set it prior to run.

Any ideas how to get Kohana to run via command line?

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using?

Comment: you're very close in that little piece of code, just have to add --uri= in front of the $command

    `exec('php index.php --uri='.$command.' > /dev/null &', $errors, $response);`

but from the rest of your question, I think it might be better to use a cronjob for it or if you use kohana3, use its HMVC-capabilities

Comment: Now you are able to do only this: `php index.php --task=demo`, where this demo is saved in `classes/Task/demo.php` as a `class Task_Demo extends Minion_Task`. For more info check here https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/minion/tasks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know you can't run the kohana files directly in command line because of its bootstrap methods.

You could do 2 things: 
export all command like functions outside kohana and run them independently.

Something else you could do is running it trough the index.php located in the kohana main folder while passing the $controller, $method variables to it so it ends up at the right object where your code is located:

For kohana 2:

```
php index.php controller/method/var1/var2
```

Kohana 3

```
php index.php --uri=controller/method/var1/var2
```

**Edit:**
Kohana has a great CLI task runner from version 3.3 onward as official module. For version 3.2 it's still an unofficial module. I suggest you use these because they give a lot of extra options on running from CLI:

- Kohana 3.2 - https://github.com/Zeelot/kohana-minion
- Kohana 3.3 - https://github.com/kohana/minion

Comment: This isn't true, you *can* run Kohana from the command line. This answer probably shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: This answer is both untrue and true. I actually explained that you can't run the kohana files directly. But you can run them trough the index.php like zombor beneath is saying(on of the developers).

I agree that I should have phrased it differently. 

Edited now ^^

Answer (score 18):

After looking into Kohana3 source code, I found that it has support for cli (`system/classes/kohana/cli.php`). You can pass 3 options (uri, method, get, post). So:-

`$ php index.php --uri="items/list"`

would call the `list` method in `Controller_Items`.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem as me. This feature has been removed in Kohana 3.3. You can no longer pass the uri like that. :(

Answer (score 7):

And Kohana2 is just `php index.php controller/method/param1/param2/etc`

Kohana was built to run on the CLI as well as web.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Kohana 3 then you can run it from the terminal.

### Example

```
php index.php --uri=controller/action
```

### Options

- --uri
- --method
- --get
- --post

Answer (score 2):

For Kohana 3, check out these [docs and source](http://v3.kohanaphp.com/guide/api/CLI).

Comment: That link doesn't seem to have a valid answer or useful instructions on the process of executing Kohana 3 on CLI.

Comment: @Alejandro It's the only *official* CLI documentation I could find. Kohana is big about their source being documentation itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue

Did you or anyone add the `SERVER_NAME` to the `index.php` file?

If so either remove the code outside the `index.php` (and or bootstrap)  OR you can wrap it it in a

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') 
{ 
   // ... 
}  else {
 //....
}
```